# mysql returning only 2 results

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_connect('localhost:3036', 'root', 'xxxx');

mysql_select_db('extractor');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT trackingno FROM xx where orderid='".$item->increment_id."'");

$compiledresults = mysql_fetch_array($query); 

foreach($compiledresults as $items){ 

echo $items."</br>";
}
```

It's always returning two values at maximum only. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure there are more than 2 results matching the condition you have specified?

Comment: I think you want to use `while($compiledresults = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))` instead of just getting the first result from `mysql_fetch_assoc($query)`, hence the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) saying _Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead_ .. and please notice the _deprecation warning_ in red.

Comment: A loop as suggested by @dbf is better because if the result is giant, enumerating it all at once is a huge memory user, while enumerating one at a time is peaceful. It will also save you 6-8 weeks of debugging

Comment: how do i echo the array, it's returning 4 array but i want the value inside the array (1 value each array)

Comment: echo $compiledresults[0]; ?

Comment: You better go for print_r($compiledresults);

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix your code to:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT trackingno FROM xx where orderid='".$item->increment_id."'");
if ($query){
  while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $data['trackingno'] ;
  } 
}
```

The reason you get 2 items is that you used `mysql_fetch_array` once. That gives you just one row from the database. First element in array is number-indexed, another is string-indexed.

So you had: `$compiledresults[0]` and `$compiledresults['trackingno']` in fact.